# same code doesn't work on different server

Tags: php

I have this code and it works fine on one server (not localhost).  I've used Ctl-A and Ctl-V to put it into a page in another different server and it doesn't work (localhost).  I just get a white blank page.  If I comment out the php it works fine, but if there's even the first variable uncommented...nothing.  What's wrong?

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP 5.3.18 on windows XP
 *
 * I don't have open_ssl active from PHP so used MCRYPT_RAND for the salt.
 * It is adequate for this exercise.
 *
 * As the encoded SALT and encrypted output are binary code i have converted all
 * the output to Base64 encoding to ensure it is HTML safe.
 *
 * It selects the appropriate default action in the 'do' select list.
 *
 * There is a new 'salt' generated at each encryption and the user is prevented from
 * changing it by making the display field as 'readonly'. Normally this would be a 'hidden' field'.
 *
 */

$isEncrypted = null; // used to set default output options
                     // i like to pre-declare the script 'global' variables


$key_size = mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);


if($_POST){ // we have some input...
$encryption_key = $_POST["key"];
$string = $_POST["msg"]; // this may be base64 encoded...


if($_POST["do"]=="encrypt"){
    $isEncrypted = true; // used to set defaults

    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,  MCRYPT_RAND); // new salt with each encryption
    $result = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryption_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
    $result = base64_encode($result); // $result is binary so encode as HTML safe.


}else{
    $isEncrypted = false; // used to set defaults

    $iv = base64_decode($_POST["iv"]); // get current salt converted back to binary format
    $string = base64_decode($string); // convert encoded text back to binary string
    $result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryption_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
}
}else{ // no input so create something useful...
  $isEncrypted = false; // used to set default actions

  $result = 'enter text to encrypt...'; // sample text
  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,  MCRYPT_RAND); // new salt
  $encryption_key = substr('testing!' . uniqid() . '!testing', 0, $key_size);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test Encryption with base64 encoding.</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main" id="main">
    <!-- heading -->
    <strong><?php echo $isEncrypted ? 'Encrypted' : 'Decrypted'; ?></strong><br/>

    <form method="POST" action="">

        <!-- do not allow the user to change the salt by setting 'readonly' -->
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo base64_encode($iv); ?>" readonly name="iv"/> <br/>

        <!-- supply a suggested password but the user can change it -->
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $encryption_key; ?>" name="key"/><br/>

        <!-- either show the encoded text as HTML safe string -->
        <!--- or show as plain text -->
        <textarea name="msg" ><?php echo $result; ?></textarea><br/>

        <!-- set the appropriate action as the default -->
        <select name="do">
          <option <?php echo $isEncrypted ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>decrypt</option>
          <option <?php echo $isEncrypted ? '' : 'selected'; ?>>encrypt</option>
        </select><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding this to the top of the page: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: Do both servers have the same version of webserver and PHP?

Comment: When you say "I just get a white blank page." the next thing you should do is find the server's error log and look to see what errors showed up there.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!  I'll do these and see...

Comment: mcrypt is not always installed, so I'd put my bet on that if it's working on one environment but not another: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: @KevinNelson you get the prize!  I had done apt-get install mcrypt and had the ini file, but not the php5enmod mcrypt step.  Now it's working.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @user1149499, okay, then I want to claim my prize :-p.  Made the comment into an answer so that you can mark it accepted if you like.  I think that's the shortest answer I've ever given.

Comment: I don't know if I should ask this as a separate question, but I'd love to know how to write the above so that the if statements call functions that encrypt and decrypt.  I tried a few different ways and didn't get anywhere.  Is it more challenging than I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcrypt is not always installed, so I'd put my bet on that if it's working on one environment but not another:

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: +1 for making my life easier, i would not have thought of that.

Comment: Thanks again!  Short answers work as nicely as long answers...if they work!  :-)